# Alternative for [OVERFLOW:HIDDEN]

Tags: html, css

I am currently working in our system and I find it difficult to use overflow in my HTML.

Please take a look at my fiddle. and try to put

```
overflow:hidden;
```

in

```
#nav-holder{
background: #333333;
padding-left: 30px;
padding-right: 30px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mjanthrax/L7vgnzvt/

You will notice that, after including `overflow:hidden` in the css, the navigation menu(hover) doesn't display.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need [display: inline-block](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/display) and set the `width` to `100%`

**inline-block**

> The element generates a block element box that will be flowed with
> surrounding content as if it were a single inline box (behaving much
> like a replaced element would)

Change

```
#nav-holder{
    background: #333333;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

to

```
#nav-holder {
    background: #333333;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7vgnzvt/4/)

You then may want to add `*{box-sizing: border-box}` at the top pf you css

[Full demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L7vgnzvt/5/)

Read more about [box-sizing here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)

[bonus](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

Comment: @Ellis what are you talking about? :-) box-sizing? then please read the ref first.