# add horizontal scrollbar in div tag without using overflow property

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want a responsive table with div tag that has scrollbar horizontally but without using overflow property of css, here is an example:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;

}

th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="overflow-x:auto">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

There are some restrictions of tag and property that I can't use such as meta tag, Overflow property(used in css), display tag and table-layout.

Comment: If you can't use the overflow properties, I'm pretty sure you're toast.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative for \[OVERFLOW:HIDDEN\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778290/alternative-for-overflowhidden)

Comment: @IbrahimAljokhadar, I don't think that's asking the same question. That question was using overflow for a different purpose than it is here.