# Is there any way to make the whole page un-scrollable without using "overflow"

Tags: html, css

I am just curious on how you can make the whole page un-scrollable without using `overflow: hidden`? Because I am trying to make an app wherein the scrollbar on the right side won't disappear. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: I have found out the answer already [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701754/how-to-disable-scroll-without-hiding-it)

Comment: you check this link too : [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778290/alternative-for-overflowhidden)